# touch.locationInView not assigning to local variable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to get to use locationInView to get the location of a touch.  When I print the locationInView to the console, the correct value is outputted.  But when I try and assign it to a local variable, that variable never gets the value and therefore the rest of my code doesn't work.  Also, this is a subclass of UIControl.

Snippet below:

```
override func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
{
    NSLog("\(touch.locationInView(self))")     // Prints out the correct location
    let newPoint = touch.locationInView(self)  // Never gets assigned to newPoint
    var calculatedIndex: Int?

    for (index, item) in labels.enumerate() {
        if item.bounds.contains(newPoint) {
            calculatedIndex = index
        }
    }

    if calculatedIndex != nil {
        selectedIndex = calculatedIndex!
        sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
    }

    return false
}
```

[image: Debugger and local variables]
[Debugger and local variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UskfI.png)

Comment: I doubt that actually happens, what is the output of logging / printing `newPoint`?

Comment: I added a snapshot of Xcode and debugger's locals and console, showing what is happening.

Comment: The Xcode debugger is known to have its fair amount of bugs, please just add a NSLog statement after your assignment of newPoint logging newPoint.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  I see that newPoint does have it's value.  The rest of my code still isn't working how I would expect.  I'll need to keep digging...thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your code locally and it all worked fine. You are probably deceived by debugger issue to show the value. You may confirm this by printing `newPoint`.

As for why your rest of the code is not getting executed, I would recommend you to check your `labels`. I think `labels.enumerate` is failing which makes your feel that code is not getting executed. Again try to print values rather than relying on debugger.

Comment: Thanks.  I see the debugger was failing me.  I also had a mix up between my bounds and frame, and therefore that wasn't selecting properly like I expected.  Threw a couple NSLog's in there and figured it all out.

Comment: Great... I guess this must be accepted answer. Could you please accept this for the benefit of others.